# How do I force cbindgen to expand macros in the current crate and include them in the output?

Tags: rust

I am including the current crate name in the cbindgen.toml file

```ini
[parse.expand]
# A list of crate names that should be run through `cargo expand` before
# parsing to expand any macros. Note that if a crate is named here, it
# will always be parsed, even if the blacklist/whitelist says it shouldn't be.**
#
# default: []
crates = ["currentcrate"]
```

I have also added a build.rs file in the current package to generate c header bindings whenever build is run. But the build fails whenever I am including the current crate name in expand section.
Even running cbindgen command line to get c headers correposponding to expanded macros is not working

Comment: *"But the build fails"* how? Please add the complete error message (e.g. from `cargo build`) as [formatted](/help/formatting) text. Also include any other resources necesary for a [mre]